# Access violation executing location 0x0000 when using my exe from a dll which links to another dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, vulkan

Here is my program.
https://github.com/ILLmew/Seagull-Engine-v2

For short, this is an tiny game-engine i wrote to learn new things and here is the question:
I have a SCore.dll for basic facilities and all other modules used this to do other things.
Now I have a SRendererVulkan.dll which links to SCore.dll and my app Sandbox.exe which links SCore.dll and SRendererVulkan.dll at load-time not runtime.

Like this below:

```
SCore.dll -------> SRendererVulkan.dll -------> Sandbox.exe  
     |                                               ^
     |                                               |
     -------------------------------------------------
```

When compiling in VS2019, it has no compile error or link error.
And when i run the program, i put some breakpoints to check if the resources for vulkan had been initialized and it seems that the whole initialization is success, everything is fine. No nullptr check failed and it shows the window. But when i close the window and enter the shutdown stage it make an assertion:
[Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTBy0.png)

I use premake as build tools and the upper dlls all links to eastl.lib and mimalloc.lib.

I try many ways including exporting the backend of SRendererVulkan.dll or exporting the whole class in VulkanRenderDevice, they all failed.

I know it is a linking error but i can not solve it so i came here and ask for help.

Comment: I doubt that this is a linking error.

Comment: In the call to vkDestroyDevice is logicalDevice a nullpointer?

Comment: No, it is ok with the backend. And i found why it failed. I new SRendererVulkan.dll in exe and delete it in SCore.dll, so it successfully to create but failed to destroy. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I new() SRendererVulkan.dll in the exe and delete it in SCore.dll. So it is successfully created, but fails to be destroyed.
Due to this operation, it raise a failure on deleting the corresponding memory allocation block and thus leads to this error.